# Format of BigDecimal number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal val = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.20);
System.out.println(a);
```

I want to store in val a value `0.20` and not `0.2`. What I can do ?

I dont think I can use `NumberFormat` in this case, when I use `NumberFormat` I must know what the length of my decimal number is! I can have 0.20 or 0.5000, I don't know the exact length of my decimal number, so I cannot use :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

or

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
```

maybe I have just 2 numbers after point or 5 numbers or more, and this program doesn't work:

```
 BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.20);//i give an example of 0.2 i can have 0.98...0
         System.out.println(a);

         NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getInstance();
         System.out.println(nf1.format(0.5000));
```

Comment: I accept but it's still 0 !! what i can do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the String constructor of BigDecimal. It preserves the scale (which is what you want).

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("0.20");
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

Comment: and if i have : 0.2222222222222222222222222222222...0 ? it exceed String ?!

Comment: You don't understand your problem. Please read the BigDecimal javadoc first.

Answer (score 7):

BigDecimal remembers the trailing zeros - with some significant side-effect:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("0.20"); 
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.2");

System.out.println(bd1);
System.out.println(bd2);
System.out.println(bd1.equals(bd2));
```

will print

```
0.20
0.2
false
```

And we need to remember, that we can't use BiGDecimal for numbers, where the decimal expansion has a period:

```
BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(3));
```

will throw an exception (what partially answers your concerns in your comments)

Comment: and if i have : 0.2222222222222222222222222222222...0 ? it exceed String ?!

Comment: (try to create it with a value, where the number of decimals exceeds the maximum length of String ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a double to `BigDecimal.valueOf()`. And `0.20` is exactly the same double as `0.2`. Pass it a String, and the result will be different, because the scale of the BigDecimal will be deduced from the number of decimals in the String:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("0.20");
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.2");

System.out.println(bd1.toPlainString() + ", scale = " + bd1.scale()); // 0.20, scale = 2
System.out.println(bd2.toPlainString() + ", scale = " + bd2.scale()); // 0.2, scale = 1

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(bd1.scale());
System.out.println(nf.format(bd1)); // 0,20 (in French locale)

nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(bd2.scale());
System.out.println(nf.format(bd2)); // 0,2 (in French locale)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer is wrong as pointed out in the comments :| thx Andreas_D

The problem is that there is no mathematical difference between 0.2 and 0.20 so your only chance is to display a certain number of digits after the decimal point. Once you store 0.2 or 0.20 in a `BigDecimal` they are indistinguishable from each other

Comment: That's, err, not the case with BigDecimal ;)

Comment: oohh sorry! didn't know that :|

Comment: (Me too, first, and it took me *hours* to debug some code where I *thought*, those two big decimals were equal :-D )