# Cannot format given Object as a Number

Tags: jsf-2, el

this piece of code throw me: Cannot format given Object as a Number

```
  private BigDecimal notional;

 public String getNotional() {
    System.out.println("notional:" + notional);
    otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
    System.out.println("notional:" + notional);
    String format = df.format(notional);
    System.out.println("notional2:" + format);


    if(notional!=null)
    notional = new BigDecimal(df.format(notional));
    return notional.toString();
 }
```

why?

```
   javax.el.ELException: /pages/emir/acknowledgedTransactions.xhtml @484,160 value="#{ackTxContractBean.firstleg.notional}":
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
```

notional: 2279713.86
notional2: 2.279.713,86

Comment: A getter should absolutely not look like this. You should just return `national` unmodified.

Comment: what i must do if i must show a different number format? and at same time i need a Bigdecimal for make an insert into the db?

Comment: Just use `<f:convertNumber>` with the right locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you are passing the format instead of the string maybe.

[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) constructor you are targeting takes a String (BigDecimal(String )) None of the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).format methods seem to take a String. Just create your BigDeciamal and then format if afterward. What type is notional anyway.

Found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653747/format-of-bigdecimal-number) which seems to do what you want.