# BigDecimal() omitting leading zero

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How I can store the BigDecimal() same as input?

I need to store real numbers using BigDecimal() which may contain following:

```
02.34
0.12
.12
0
000.000
```

I used the following approach :

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
BigDecimal[] amount = new BigDecimal[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    amount[i]=sc.nextBigDecimal();
}
```

But while printing, it prints formatted. Like this:

```
2.34
0.12
0.12
0.000
0
```

I want it should be same as inputted. Therefore please let me know that how could I manage to store inputs intact.

Answer (score 5):

the following code should solve your problem, Keep your string as is and convert it into BigDecimal only when you are comparing

```
 Arrays.sort(s, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a1, String a2) { 
           BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(a1);
            BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a2);
            return a.compareTo(b);

        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since input is originally a string, the only way to store it intact is to store it as a `String`.

If you later need to do some math on the numbers, convert them then. You could also possibly store them as both `String` and `BigDecimal` in an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store input intact, store it as a `String`. This is exactly the built-in type dedicated to storing character sequences exactly as entered.

`BigDecimal`, on the other hand, has a numeric representation with no mechanism for storing its decimal input. In fact, you can initialize `BigDecimal` without providing a decimal representation at all - e.g. through a sequence of arithmetical operations, in which case the initial representation would not be applicable at all.

If you need to do this in many places, make a class for it. Store the original string, along wit `BigDecimal` that it represents. This way you would be able to do the conversion only once, and keep the original representation along with it:

```
class OrigBigDecimal {
    private String orig;
    private BigDecimal val;
    public OrigBigDecimal(String s) {
        orig = s;
        val = new BigDecimal(s);
    }
    public String toString() { return s; }
    public BigDecimal getVal() { return val; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach this:

1- You can create a small elegant object that has 2 variables, a BigDecimal and a string, and its constructor takes the input as a string, store it in a string and parse it and store it in the BigDecimal.

2- You can configure the BigDecimal output format per input:

[Format of BigDecimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653747/format-of-bigdecimal-number)

[Format a BigDecimal as String with max 2 decimal digits, removing 0 on decimal part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269045/format-a-bigdecimal-as-string-with-max-2-decimal-digits-removing-0-on-decimal-p)